# JAXBElement over an ArrayList?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

How to marshall a List of JAXBElement ?

I've got one POJO I cannot annotate, for instance:

```
public class APojo {

private String aString;

public APojo() { 
    super(); 
}

public String getAString() {
    return aString;
}

public void setAString(String aString) {
    this.aString = aString;
}
}
```

So I'm doing this

```
APojo aPojo = new APojo();
aPojo.setaString("a string");       
JAXBElement<APojo> aJAXBedPojo = new JAXBElement<APojo>(new QName("apojo"), APojo.class, aPojo);
```

Which is correctly being marshaled.

However

```
List<JAXBElement<APojo>> list = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<APojo>>();
```

Is not working: when I' doing this

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(APojo.class, ArrayList.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.marshal(list, System.out);
```

The runtime raises:

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.util.ArrayList" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

Which is normal since ArrayList is not annotated.

I know I can create a wrapper around ArrayList and annotate it with a @XmlRootElement so I can marshall this wrapper.

I'm looking for a solution without such a wrapper. Is it possible to create a JAXBElement with T being an ArrayList ? Or something similar ?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an xsd to create any/all of the jaxb bindings you will need?

Comment: Yes one: I want to understand how to do it by hand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution seems to build a wrapper like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4145801/254439).

As my goal was to return my list from a REST web service, it was even simpler for me to wrap my list inside a [javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html), like this

```
new GenericEntity<List<APojo>>(aPojo) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend you use an [XmlAdapter](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html).  You can simply register the adapter with your marshaller and it will use your annotated adapter class in place of the class you can't annotate.

Also, I think a wrapper class would be cleaner than trying to do something without a wrapper.

That being said, if you really wanted to, you could try the following:

```
List<JAXBElement<APojo>> list = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<APojo>>();
JAXBElement<List<JAXBElement<APojo>>> listElement = new JAXBElement<List<JAXBElement<APojo>>>(new QName("apojolist"), List.class, list);
```

Comment: In fact I've already tried that but Eclipse tells me then that "The constructor JAXBElement<List<JAXBElement<APojo>>>(QName, Class<List>, List<JAXBElement<APojo>>) is undefined". I don't understand clearly why :)

Comment: The "right" code must be very close to your answer but I don't find it :(